# SendGrid and PHP to multiple recipents

Tags: php, email

I'm using sendgrid to send out html emails from a document system I'm building. When a file uploads sendgrid needs to email all those associated with that case. I have everything working for individual emails and I can customs the template I have saved but cant send the email to multiple recipients

I have generated an array of recipients

```
$email = array(j.bloggs@bloggs.com, j.doe@me.net, d.smith@smith.co.uk);
```

I want to pass this into my sendgrid email object to send to them all

```
private function send() {
    $sg       = new \SendGrid(self::$key);
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post(self::$mail);
    return $response->statusCode();
}     

public function file_saved($file="", $case="") {
    self::$from    = new SendGrid\Email($this->fromName, $this->fromEmail);
    self::$to      = new SendGrid\Email($this->toName, $this->toEmail);
    self::$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Hello, Email!");
    self::$mail    = new SendGrid\Mail(
        self::$from, 
        $this->subject, 
        self::$to, 
        self::$content
    );

    $str = "<p>A file has been successfully uploaded to {$case->case_name} ({$case->case_code}).</p>
    <br />
    <p>{$file->file_name} - ".size($file->file_size)."</p>";

    self::$mail->personalization[0]->addSubstitution("-name-", $this->toName);
    self::$mail->personalization[0]->addSubstitution("-str-", $str);
    self::$mail->personalization[0]->addSubstitution("-btn-", "Download File");
    self::$mail->personalization[0]->addSubstitution("-url-", HTTP.BASE_URL.DS.'uploads'.DS.$file->file_path);
    self::$mail->setTemplateId("2f845487-6243-4562-b6fb-022185b7fde7");

    if (!$this->send() == 202) {
        return false;
    } 

    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to use the personalization->to and pass that the array but get the error

```
Call to a member function to() on null in includes/classes/mail.php on line <b>82</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a loop that went through each recipient and sent them an email, not as efficient as generating a multiple to: list but for now its working until I get a response from the sendgrid dev team

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->email = array(j.bloggs@bloggs.com, j.doe@me.net, d.smith@smith.co.uk);

private function send() {
    $sg       = new \SendGrid(self::$key);
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post(self::$mail);
    return $response->statusCode();
}     

public function file_saved($file="", $case="") {

    $str = "<p>A file has been successfully uploaded to {$case->case_name} ({$case->case_code}).</p>
        <br />
        <p>{$file->file_name} - ".size($file->file_size)."</p>";

    self::$from    = new SendGrid\Email($this->fromName, $this->fromEmail);
    self::$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Hello, Email!");

    foreach($this->email as $email_addr) {
        self::$to      = new SendGrid\Email($this->toName, $email_addr);        
        self::$mail    = new SendGrid\Mail(
            self::$from, 
            $this->subject, 
            self::$to, 
            self::$content
        );
        self::$mail->personalization[0]->addSubstitution("-str-", $str);
        self::$mail->personalization[0]->addSubstitution("-btn-", "Download File");
        self::$mail->personalization[0]->addSubstitution("-url-", HTTP.BASE_URL.DS.'uploads'.DS.$file->file_path);
        self::$mail->setTemplateId("2f845487-6243-4562-b6fb-022185b7fde7");

        if (!$this->send() == 202) {
            $response[$address] = false;
        }

        else {
            $response[$address] = true;
        }

    }

    return $response; // contains true/false for each email address if sent or not.
}
```